# Openvpn don't see changes in Mysql database

Tags: python, mysql, openvpn

On OpenVPN, I installed the script "post_auth_mac_address_checking.py" to check clients's MAC addresses during vpn connection.
https://openvpn.net/vpn-server-resources/access-server-post-auth-script-host-checking/
It works fine with local MySQL database for the Mac addresses.

My problem is when I make some changes in the mysql database (add or delete mac addresses), OpenVPN (sacli?) don't see the changes.

How can I "force" openvpn to execute the script for each connection ?
Is there a cache for script I need to refresh ?

Thank you for your help!

the script :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import uuid
import re
import MySQLdb
import sys

from pyovpn.plugin import *

# f this is set to "NONE" or "DISABLED" then the server administrator must
# always manually register each MAC/UUID address by hand on the command line.
first_login_ip_addr="NONE"

# If False or undefined, AS will call us asynchronously in a worker thread.
# If True, AS will call us synchronously (server will block during call),
# however we can assume asynchronous behavior by returning a Twisted
# Deferred object.
SYNCHRONOUS=False

# Get authorized MAC addresses in the mysql database
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host='127.0.0.1',user='xxx',passwd='xxx',db='xxx')

with conn as cur:
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED")
    result_iso = cur.fetchall()[0]
    cur.execute("SELECT mac_address FROM whitelist_mac;")
    results = cur.fetchall()
    whitelistmac = [row[0] for row in results]

# this function is called by the Access Server after normal VPN or web authentication
def post_auth(authcred, attributes, authret, info):
    print "********** POST_AUTH", authcred, attributes, authret, info

    #get the phone's MAC address
    from uuid import getnode 
    MAC_phone = (':'.join(re.findall('..', '%012x' % uuid.getnode())))

    # get user's property list, or create it if absent
    proplist = authret.setdefault('proplist', {})

    # user properties to save - we will use this to pass the hw_addr_save property to be
    # saved in the user property database.
    proplist_save = {}

    error = ""

    # The 'error' text goes to the VPN client and is shown to the user.
    # The 'print' lines go to the log file at /var/log/openvpnas.log (by default).

    if attributes.get('vpn_auth'):                  # only do this for VPN authentication
        hw_addr = authcred.get('client_hw_addr')    # MAC address reported by the VPN client
        username = authcred.get('username')         # User name of the VPN client login attempt
        clientip = authcred.get('client_ip_addr')   # IP address of VPN client login attempt

        if hw_addr or MAC_phone:
                if (hw_addr or MAC_phone) in whitelistmac:
                    print "***** POST_AUTH MAC CHECK: account user name         : %s" % username
                    print "***** POST_AUTH MAC CHECK: client IP address         : %s" % clientip
            if hw_addr:
                        print "***** POST_AUTH MAC CHECK: PC MAC address            : %s" % hw_addr
            else:
                print "***** POST_AUTH MAC CHECK: Phone MAC address         : %s" % MAC_phone
                print "***** POST_AUTH MAC CHECK: connection attempt        : SUCCESS"
                else:
                    error = "Le client n'est pas autorisé à se connecter."
                    print "***** POST_AUTH MAC CHECK: account user name         : %s" % username
                    print "***** POST_AUTH MAC CHECK: client IP address         : %s" % clientip
            if hw_addr:
                        print "***** POST_AUTH MAC CHECK: PC MAC address            : %s" % hw_addr 
            else:
                        print "***** POST_AUTH MAC CHECK: Phone MAC address         : %s" % MAC_phone

                    print "***** POST_AUTH MAC CHECK: connection attempt        : FAILED"
        else:
            error = "L'adresse MAC du client n'a pas été diffusé."
            print "***** POST_AUTH MAC CHECK: account user name         : %s" % username
            print "***** POST_AUTH MAC CHECK: client IP address         : %s" % clientip
        print "***** POST_AUTH MAC CHECK: Phone MAC address         : %s" % MAC_phone
            print "***** POST_AUTH MAC CHECK: PC MAC address            : NONE REPORTED"
        print "***** POST_AUTH MAC CHECK: action taken              : VPN connection denied with a suitable error message."
            print "***** POST_AUTH MAC CHECK: connection attempt        : FAILED"

    # process error, if one occurred
    if error:
        authret['status'] = FAIL
        authret['reason'] = error          # this error string is written to the server log file
        authret['client_reason'] = error   # this error string is reported to the client user

    return authret, proplist_save

if conn:
    conn.close()
```

Comment: Nobody have an idea ?...

Comment: Maybe my question is not clear enough ? :(

Answer (score 0):

From [OpenVPN Documentation](https://openvpn.net/vpn-server-resources/access-server-post-auth-script-host-checking/):

*"If you make alterations to the mac.py file then you will need to use the above commands again to load the new version of the script into the configuration database, and to reload the configuration of the Access Server again."*

You need to remove the old script:

`cd /usr/local/openvpn_as/scripts
./sacli -k auth.module.post_auth_script ConfigDel
./sacli start`

Then, add the new script:

`cd /usr/local/openvpn_as/scripts
./sacli -k auth.module.post_auth_script --value_file=/root/mac.py ConfigPut
./sacli start`

(Assuming your script it located in `/root/mac.py`)

Comment: Thank you very much for you response, but I don't make any changes in this script (I modified the original script once time). I just make some MySql data changes and this script don't see anything.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to move

```
with conn as cur:
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED")
    result_iso = cur.fetchall()[0]
    cur.execute("SELECT mac_address FROM whitelist_mac;")
    results = cur.fetchall()
    whitelistmac = [row[0] for row in results]
```

Into the `post_auth` function, otherwise it will only be executed when the script loads the first time.